# Implicit functions differentiation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

While differentiating an implicit function , I ended up treating du/dx as a fraction and I am not quite happy about that . I want to know whether it's mathematically accurate to do that .
Question: Differentiate x(y)^3 with respect to x by not using product rule .

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I have put down an example .

Comment: Do you mean $(x(y))^3$ or $xy^3$?

Comment: @GitGud the second one .

Comment: @AbuBardewa This has nothing to do with implicit differentiation, though. This just a partial derivative.

Comment: I did not use the product rule . I differentiated it and came to an expression where I ended up treating that as fraction and cancelling it out . I checked it using the product rule as well and it works. So I was wondering how is it possible to treat it as a fraction.